# Prove that a continuous function is bijective

Tags: real-analysis, continuity

I have a function $f:\mathbb{R}\rightarrow\mathbb{R}$ which is continuous and has the property that $|f(x)-f(y)|\geq|x-y| \ \forall x,y \in \mathbb{R}$. I need to prove that this function is bijective. 
 Honestly, I didn't knew where to begin so I tried with the deifinition of the bijective function, but couldn't found the connection with continuity.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Hint: Injectivity. Let $x\ne y$. Then $0< |x-y| \leq |f(x)-f(y)|$ and so $f(x)\ne f(y)$. Done.

Comment: Ok, that was pretty simple. Now how about surjectivity?

Comment: $\forall y \in \mathbb{R}$, there is a $x \in \mathbb{R}$ such that $f(x) = y$ and since $f$ is coninuous that statement is satisfied, right?

Comment: It requires continuity.